# How can I set scroll offset after reset content inset?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a problem with UITextView. I must reset this content inset because I have to add some content to top and bottom.
I wrote a code in textViewDidChanged.
Because I'll set something, to textView's bottom, when I typing blah-blah, something is repositioned, otherwise blah-blah is typed on the something. I don't want that. So i wrote a code in textViewDidChange.

Here's my code:

```
UIEdgeInsets newInset = self.textView.contentInset;
newInset.top = 50;
newInset.bottom = 1000; // just example
self.textView.contentInset = newInset;
```

Ok done.

I reset the content inset, but textView's scrol always points to the end of uitextView.
I want scroll offset is set to typing position.

How can I fix it? I just want resize my textview's content inset.

How can I do it? Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

As UITextView inherits from UIScrollView you can set the Scroll Indicator insets by calling:

```
UIEdgeInsets scrollInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0);
yourTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollInsets;
```

This will give you 20px at the top and 30px at the bottom of your textview.